# Experience Cloud Email Settings - Can we add links in footer text?

Tags: community, email, experience-cloud, email-settings

Is it possible to embed URLs/links in footer text of Experience Cloud email settings?

I've tried a few variations:

- `<a href="https://google.com">Click here</a>`
- `https://google.com`
- `google.com`

None of these seem to create links in emails.

---

### Screenshot of settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.

Turns out Gmail had defaulted my Chatter emails as spam, and automatically un-linked any URL.

After fixing the spam issue the links work just fine.